# Card flip animation in flexbox layout

Tags: css, flexbox, flip

I have a two-part issue. First, I'm struggling to implement a card flip animation to cards in an existing flexbox grid layout since all of the solutions I've come across apply `position: absolute` on the cards, which breaks the layout and makes the rows overlap each other as they have almost no height. I also can't manually set the heights as it's based on variable content/viewports.

Secondly, I also can't get the animation itself working. I'm going for CSS approach triggered in jQuery. I tried the plugin jQuery Flip, but that also had the positioning issue.

Basically, I'm looking for a card flip animation solution that doesn't need the cards to be set to `position: absolute`, or does, but allows for multiple rows that don't have a fixed height. I don't mind using jQuery.

CSS:

```
.events-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: 31.3%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.card .card-flip-cont {
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.card .card-front,
.card .card-back {
  position: absolute; /* Need to get rid of */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .card-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}

.card-flip-cont .card-flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
```

Layout:

```
<div class="events-row">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-flip-cont">
      <div class="card-face card-front">
        <div class="card-img four-three-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/gsnJi.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <h2>Event title</h2>
          <h3>Event date</h3>
          <h3>Event venue</h3>
          <p>
            Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          </p>
          <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="button purple-button">Buy Tickets</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-face card-back">
        <div class="card-img four-three-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/gsnJi.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <h2>Event title2</h2>
          <h3>Event date2</h3>
          <h3>Event venue2</h3>
          <p>
            Cu cum quem eros periculis, volutpat tractatos accommodare eu has, ex singulis assueverit usu.
          </p>
          <div class="button-cont">
            <div class="button purple-button">Buy Tickets</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.card-front .button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('.card-flip-cont').addClass('flipped');
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/oBeXzq